# Scaling a JSON model from Clara.IO with Three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, models

I am new to Three.JS and have been practicing making scenes and models. I have loaded a Washing machine model into my scene and have managed to place it where I want. I am now trying to scale it (make it bigger) but I'm not sure how.

I currently have:

```
var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
objectLoader.load("models/machinethreejs/machine.json", function ( wm ) {

scene.add( wm );
wm.translateZ(275);
wm.translateX(150);
wm.translateY(55);

} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

three.js has a good documentation. Here there are all object/method in a Object3d : [Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D)
You can scale an object with the method `object.scale.set(xScale, yScale, zScale)`